# How to preview site on mobile emulators

Tags: mobile

Hi I am developing a mobile version of my WordPress site using WP Touch Pro, are there any good emulators so I can see the results on different platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup:
http://www.electricplum.com/dlsim.html

will show you ipad and iphone simulations.

Comment: Just tested the Lite Version for win and it seems to not really work.

Comment: excellent thanks so much. Now just need one for Android and Blackberry

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a Mac, you can use the free [iOS SDK](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) which includes an iOS Simulator. [Android also has one](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html); it takes a few extra steps to setup, but it's also free and cross-platform. [Blackberry has one as well](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp), pretty much all platforms do. I develop mobile sites all the time and these are the tools I use, and they're invaluable.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21831/how-to-test-drive-google-android-on-your-pc-without-buying-a-phone/

Answer (score 1):

This has a few different emulations available: http://mobiletest.me/

Answer (score 0):

This is a great extension  for chrome , [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg)